# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt failed

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\franc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\Users\franc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "C:\Users\franc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 18, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "C:\Users\franc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1363, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "C:\Users\franc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1344, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "C:\Users\franc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 978, in __init__
    ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
  File "C:\Users\franc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 264, in findSystemFonts
    fontfiles.update(win32InstalledFonts(fontext=fontext))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall `matplotlib` in many ways, but I still get the above error.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268935/why-is-matplotlib-failing-on-import-matplotlib-pyplot-as-plt), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302091/error-when-import-matplotlib-pyplot-as-plt), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243203/import-matplotlib-pyplot-as-plt-fails-with-error-about-python-tk) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573248/how-to-resolve-import-matplotlib-pyplot-as-plt-error) helps you

Comment: thanks, but I've already seen this links. I'm using anaconda

Comment: which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: matplotlib 3.0.0

Comment: Then it's [this new error](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12173) which is not yet fixed.

Comment: so, can i solve this installing another version? which do you suggest me?

Comment: In conda list  I have this output:                                                          
matplotlib                3.0.0            py35h7b168c4_1    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.0.0                     <pip>

Comment: I think for the moment you may revert to version 2.2.3. I'm not sure what the solution to this problem will be in the end, it's still being discussed, but there should probably be a bugfix release soon.

Comment: thank you! Now it works with the version 2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met this problem and fixxed it with installing the old version. Try:

`pip uninstall matplotlib`

`pip install -v matplotlib==2.2.2`

It seem that this bug casued by the incorrect use of pathlib package in matplotlib.font_manager.py